# Possessive word order "English's accommodation spending on holiday reached 55% in 2012"

Tags: word-order, possessives

Is this sentence correct to describe a chart? Sometimes I get confused between using *x of x* versus *x's*.

I want to say that the British spent 55% on accommodation on weekend holidays in 2022. Does this sentence convey what I mean?

> English's accommodation spending on holiday reached 55% in 2012.

Comment: I don't think this is a suitable context for using a possessive form. Just go with *The average cost of accommodation **in Britain** was 55% (of average income?) in 2022.*  But "accommodation" includes people paying both *rent and mortgages*, which are significantly different types of outgoings, so maybe you should focus on *one* of those.

Comment: ...actually, I don't understand the context. What is "accommodation spending on holiday", and what is it 55% of?

Comment: Guessing that Brits spend 55% of their holiday expense on the hotel they stay in. English's? No.

Comment: British is not the same as English, so besides the fact that "English's" is weird, it's possibly incorrect technically.

Comment: I am not a Brit, but I suspect "on weekend holidays" and "on holiday" may not invoke the same meaning.

Comment: It looks like the proportion of holiday costs spent on holiday accommodation rather than transport or food or entertainment or other things.  *Britons'* would be better than *English's*

Comment: What is it that you think *English’s* means as a possessive noun that a simple *English* adjective fails to convey?

Comment: Why not say "The British spent 55% on accommodation on weekend holidays in 2022"   (55% of what??)

Answer (score -2):

In general, it's fine to use a possessive, like "X's Y" as a replacement for "the Y of X." This could work with, say, "Americans' spending on accommodations." Note, that's both a plural ("Americans") *and* a possessive.

The difficulty in this case is that the plural for residents of Britain is tricky. There are many nationality-type words that don't have a convenient plural; we don't say "Frenches." You can speak collectively of "*the* French," but this doesn't lend itself well to a possessive ("the French's"). You might hear terms like "Frenchmen," but these are outdated and have sexist as well as perhaps racist overtones.

Things get even more complicated for England, because "England," "Britain," and "the United Kingdom" can be distinct ideas, and sometimes we carelessly substitute one term for another. If you're reporting data, it's best to be very clear. Are Scotland, Northern Ireland, etc. included? Are you speaking of an ethnic group or citizens of a political country?

So the best option is, as you suggested in a comment, to expand the phrase. Perhaps "The spending of residents of the UK on holiday accommodations." (Come to think of it, *that's* one that could use a plural possessive: "UK residents' spending...")

One other note: British English does speak of going "on holiday," so it's the logical choice of phrase in this case, but American English tends to say "on vacation." Or if your audience is American you might use the American phrase even when speaking of the UK.

Comment: Really? You think "England's accommodation spending" is a credible noun phrase? I don't. It's not a meaningful "single value" (as might be spent by the UK government), and nowhere near everyone that lives in England would actually *pay* any part of it.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Ah, I actually read the question too quickly and thought of it as governmental spending. A possessive could still be possible, like "Americans' spending on accommodations," but the plural for Brits is tricky. I'll edit.

Comment: That's exactly what I was thinking. I'd also suggest that a possessive in such contexts would tend to imply *money paid **abroad***, but probably much if not most of the 55% OP is referring to is money spent *in the UK* - so it didn't really "cost the country" anything. (Like *Keep it in the family!* :)

Comment: "England's accommodation spending" is fine. It means the same as "England's spending on accommodation". No matches for that, but there are plenty of hits for e.g. "the UK's food spending", [example](https://www.thembsgroup.co.uk/external/ms-increases-focus-on-ocado-food-delivery-operation/), and for "accommodation spending".

Comment: @StuartF For *England’s*, you can simply use *English*. The adjective, not the possessive.

Comment: Thank you all . Words are not sufficient to express how grateful I am to all of you .( England's accommodation spending) . Should I restructure that sentence and say ( The proportion of accommodation spending on holiday by English people reached 55% in 2012) is it better? I feel some member aren't agree.